# getting [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using nested inside the elasticsearch query along with sort. when I execute without sort query is working but when I include sort it gives the messages [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]. I am building this query in python. Thanks in advance.

```
    query = {
            'bool': {
            'should': [
                {'nested': {
                    'path': 'profile.summay',
                    'query': {
                        'query_string': {
                            'query': 'machine learning',
                            'fields': ['profile.summay.desc'],
                            'default_operator': "AND"
                            }
                    }
                }},
                {'nested': {
                    'path': 'internal.summary',
                    'query': {
                        'query_string': {
                            'query': 'machine learning',
                            'fields': ['internal.summary.desc'],
                            'default_operator': "AND"
                        }
                    }
                }}
            ]
        },
        "sort": [
            {
                'profile.summary.date':{
                        'order' : 'asc',
                        "nested": { "path": "profile.summary" }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es_client = Elasticsearch(['some aws url'])
response = es_client.search(index=index_name, query=query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR;

You have a your `sort` placed wrong.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "profile.summay",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "machine learning",
                "fields": ["profile.summay.desc"],
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "internal.summary",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "machine learning",
                "fields": ["internal.summary.desc"],
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "profile.summary.date": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": { "path": "profile.summary" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

According to the documentation [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#sort-search-results), the `sort` key need to be on the same depth as the `query` key. Not a level deeper.

You code needs to go from

```
{
  "query": {
    ... query,
    
    "sort": [
      ... sort
    ]
  }
}
```

To:

```
{
  "query": {
    ... query
  },
  "sort": [
    ... sort
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this way as well but I am getting "RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [query]')" error. Between I am using python to build the query and passing as same as which I posted in the question.

Comment: Ahhh I understand better why the your query format felt wrong.
(1) disprove my edit on you question, (2) look a the documentation of the python fucntion you are calling they must be another parameter for sorting no ?

Comment: What lib do you use ? maybe post a snippet of your code

Comment: I have edited the question where it contains the lib information and code snippet